# How buffering an observable<any> when count or max time avoiding emit empty arrays?

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I need show the recent 5 items from a backend. I should buffering the last 10 items from observable, but observable might has just 0..4 items and never make the buffer, so I need a maxtime of 2000ms. The issue is I tested with: `bufferTime(2000, null, 5)` but this emit empty arrays. How can I avoid the observable emits empty arrays? Buffer should be hold always the last 10 items and only emit new buffer when a new item is added.

```
// [A,B,C]       - after 2s,      buffer -> [A,B,C]
// [A,B,C]       - after 2s,      buffer -> [] --> AVOID THIS
// [A,B,C]       - after 2s,      buffer -> [] --> AVOID THIS
// [A,B,C,D,E]   - after count 5, buffer -> [A,B,C,D,E]
// [A,B,C,D,E,F] - after count 5, buffer -> [B,C,D,E,F]
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferTime

Answer (score 5):

You can [`filter`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) empty arrays after applying `bufferTime` operator. Something like:

```js
myObservable$.pipe(
  bufferTime(2000, null, 5),
  filter(items => items.length > 0)
)
```